# How to set a value when the page loads in Android?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am creating an Android application and I am stuck at one point without knowing what to do. I am calling a webservice and get a JSON value. Then I set that value to a `TextView` field. But the problem I am facing is when the page is loaded, it's getting late to set the value to that `TextView`. And sometimes that value is not set to that `TextView`. So I have to check that before proceeding to another function and if the value is not set to then call again the following method.

Call the web service and get the value and set the text to the
 `TextValue`

```
private void getJsonRequest() {
    String tag_string_req = "req_data";

    request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "URL", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                if (jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("res")) {

                    JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("res");
                    JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(0);
                    String value = obj.getString("value");

                    spin.setText(value);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Value Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hashMap.put("uid", userID);
            return hashMap;
        }
    };
    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(15 * 1000, 1,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request, tag_string_req);
}
```

Then I called that method inside `onCreate()`.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //There are more codes,
   getJsonRequest();
}
```

So what I need is I need to set that value when the page loads. Before I can see the page that value must be set. How can I do that?

Comment: It would be bad to hold UI, instead show progressbar to hold user interaction.

Comment: there is something called **ASYNC TASK**

Comment: I really appreciate if anyone can give some code snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `progress dialog` to show to user that you are fetching data

```
  //initialize the progress dialog and show it
  progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
  progressDialog.setMessage("Getting data..");
  progressDialog.show();
```

This would be before sending `request`

Then in `onResponse` after setting the text in the textView you call this

```
  progressDialog.dismiss();
```

You also should dismiss the progress dialog in `onErrorResponse`

**EDIT:**

If you should wait for the value of the returned `JSON` because you will this that value in further implementation you can set a `boolean` flag this this

```
  private boolean mHasReceivedData = false;
```

Then in the `onCreate` method, you change it like this

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //There are more codes,
   getJsonRequest();

   if(mHasReceivedData){
    //here you use the returned data.
```

}
}

And in the request success you add this line

```
  mHasReceivedData = true;
```

This way you assure that the value of the the returned `JSON` is set before using it so there will be no empty textView.

Comment: Can't I do that when the page loads? When the page loads completely value needs to be set.

Comment: I didn't get what you want to achieve? Can you please explain to me ?

Comment: When the activity loads I need to set that `JSON` value to the text field. Like a default value. No waiting time. How can I do that?

Comment: You can't do that , because waiting time depends on your server delay and internet connection speed. SO there is nothing you can do about the waiting time, but if you need the `JSON` value for further functions and you should only execute those function when you get your `JSON` value, please tell and I have a solution for you.

Comment: No it won't because your `volley` request is already asynchronous.

Comment: Can you suggest me a way to achieve this?

Comment: @HasithaMJayawardana Take a look at my edited answer please.

Answer (score 4):

```
private void getJsonRequest() {
String tag_string_req = "req_data";

request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "URL", new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
      progressDialog.dismiss();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            if (jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("res")) {

                JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("res");
                JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(0);
                String value = obj.getString("value");

                spin.setText(value);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Value Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
}) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hashMap.put("uid", userID);
        return hashMap;
    }
};
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(15 * 1000, 1,
    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching The File....");
progressDialog.show();
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request, tag_string_req);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution i suggest is creating an object and synchronzie on it,this will guarantee the textview is set before your user see the page, but it is a bad practice to do so.